# Magento products and invoice query

Tags: magento-1.9

i am using magento 1.9 with neoshop theme, i am new to magento and i create a New Arrivals category that i need to include those products that is newly posted with pagination. another question is please let me know how to configure sales invoice format of magento.

thank you